# Azure - HTTP Server Errors from FrontEnd only detected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-diagnostics

I am trying to analyze below Azure observation when checked under "Diagnose and Solve Problems" feature - Web App Down. Azure SLA is 99.99% but it shows organic SLA - 99.98%. My App Service Plan is S1 and having only one application. Application is limited to business client but publicly hosted.

client has not raised any concern about web app down. but below observation shows site was down as it is listed under Web App Down feature.  I see this observation daily. How do I interpret this?

[image]

[image]